# How to apply a heading to the first line in a table cell?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to apply a Heading style to the first line of text in the A1 table cell for each table in the document. It doesn't use word wrapping.

```
Dim CurrentTable As Table
Dim head1 As Style, head2 As Style, head3 As Style, head4 As Style
Set head1 = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
Set head2 = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
Set head3 = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 3")
Set head4 = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 4")

For Each CurrentTable In ActiveDocument.Tables

    With CurrentTable.Cell(1, 1)     
        .Range.Style = head1
    End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, your 'line' is a paragraph, in which case use:

.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Style = head1

Comment: Perfect! I didn't even think of that...Thank you!